# VBA Tab Key putting actual Tab Value in Text Box instead of navigating to next control

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA form (in Excel if that matters) that contains text boxes.

On three occasions, I have found myself pressing the tab key to navigate to the next control, but instead an actual TAB is being put in the text box.

The form normally acts as it should, but it does concern me that this gremlin is showing up sporadically.

It has shown up on Office 2003 as well as Office 2007 on two different computers.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and, if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour occasionally with no obvious solution. Closing and re-opening Excel usually fixes it but that's not exactly ideal

Comment: agreed.  
In the three instances I witnessed, the following methods fixed it:  

1.  Click on a command button and come back to textbox. (This was the first time I saw this behavior and happened while my client was giving a demo to his employees.  He looked over at me with a puzzled look and I had no idea how to fix as I had not seen it before.  It was a little embarrassing.).  Interestingly enough, it has happened twice to me since that demo.
2.  Shift + Tab to go to previous control 
3.  Close and reopen the form

Comment: @tmdean can you show the code behind the form and textbox to see what is happening?

Comment: There's lots of code behind the form I'm having this problem with. One thing I suspect is causing the issue is I have a Change event on all the fields in the form. I'll try to reduce the code to a minimized version that exhibits the problem - the issue is that the problem is difficult to reproduce. It only happens about 5% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem 100% of the time by launching Excel, immediately pulling up the form, and holding down the tab key.

If I change any code at all in the form and resave the workbook, the problem goes away. I'm going to chalk this up to a fluke compilation error within VBA.

Comment: I followed your instructions and reproduced too.  Excellent find, my friend!  Marking as answer since we know the cause and how to fix.  BTW, I like the profile photo; reminds me of days of killing red and blue blobs to earn the favor of sexy women and their 8-bit dresses.

Answer (score 1):

I created a form with three text boxes. I entered characters and tabbed onto the next for some time without being able to duplicate your problem.

The only way I can get an tab into the text box is by entering Ctrl+Tab.  This might be embarrassing but backspace removes it so it is not a major issue.  Is it possible that you are accidentally pressing Ctrl at the same time?

I find occasionally that if I mispress a key that the cursor jumps to somewhere else on the screen.  I am not quite sure what I mean by "mispress"; it seems to be something to do with pressing two keys at once.  This seems to be a feature of modern keyboards and how they detect which key has been pressed because I have encountered it on many different computers.  The implication is that by mispressing a key, a control character (perhaps tab or ctrl+tab) is generated.

I also tried the following which worked and conceals the problem by removing the tab and moving on to the next control.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

  If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, Chr(9)) <> 0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, Chr(9), "")
    TextBox2.SetFocus
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick work-around, use this code in the control's Exit event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox1.Text = VBA.Replace(TextBox1.Text, VBA.Chr(9), "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this behaviour in my coworkers' computer for several years now, while mine works fine. I have set all the Checkboxes TabStop property to False. It seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently windows sometimes runs script on background that causes excel to loose focus on textbox and instead of jumping to the next box in index it just puts an actual indent tab in the textbox, the solution that i found was to press Ctrl + Tab twice to get out of excel and return to the form and then when you press tab it goes back to normal, you can also delete de indent before or after hitting Tab again.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `TabKeyBehavior` property to `False` to get "Tab jumps to next field" behavior.

Comment: Hmmm...it is set to False by default.  

I did a quick search on that property name and found this post:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44922  




It had the following code snippit suggestion:  

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Ctl As Control
    For Each Ctl In UserForm1.Controls
        MsgBox TypeName(Ctl)
        Select Case TypeName(Ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                Ctl.TabKeyBehavior = False
        End Select
    Next Ctl
End Sub

I will try that and see if it works.  Ty for quick reply.

Comment: @ray: This bit of code does nothing else but setting the property to `False` for all textboxes. That's nothing you couldn't do right in the designer, so why use it at all.

Comment: Because when something doesn't work and you've tried the logical route...sometimes you need to try something illogical to see if you can make it work.

Your suggestion was helpful, but not applicable.

Comment: @ray: Okay... so have you found the reason?

Comment: No Tom.  Unfortunately not yet.  And I reproduced the behavior again with with the code implemented above.  Again, during another demo so I did not have time to troubleshoot.
Closing the form and opening it back up fixed the behavior.

Wish I could step into that VBA code to see what's going on.  I'll keep my eyes posted for it again.

It's like the TabKeyBehavior is set to true...even though it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the problem:

```
Public Sub MoveFocusToNextControl(xfrmFormName As UserForm, _
xctlCurrentControl As control)

Dim xctl As control
Dim lngTab As Long, lngNewTab As Long

On Error Resume Next

' Move focus to the next control in the tab order
lngTab = xctlCurrentControl.TabIndex + 1
    For Each xctl In xfrmFormName.Controls
        lngNewTab = xctl.TabIndex
        ' An error will occur if the control does not have a TabIndex property;
        ' skip over those controls.
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If lngNewTab = lngTab Then
                xctl.SetFocus
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next xctl
Set xctl = Nothing
Err.Clear
End Sub
```