# Excel VBA: Cannot tab through Userform objects after executing ActiveWorkbook.save

Tags: excel, vba

This is in Excel VBA for Microsoft Office 2007. OS is Windows 10.

Abstract:
In a userform, I can use tab to cycle through the form's fields/objects, and then after running a function that has Activeworkbook.save in it I can no longer cycle through the form's fields and pressing Enter no longer activates the default command button. If Activeworkbook.save is commented out the aforementioned problem doesn't occur. Why is this happening and how do I avoid this?

EDIT: The issue only manifests after I close excel and open the macro file again. The first time the macro runs and is interacted with it works fine. Only when its run again does the bug appear. Also, in the terminate event function of the aforementioned user form I also have an Activeworkbook.save line.

EDIT2: Sharing code of the userformtermination function.

The function in question is a Submitbuttonclicked event which stores time, date, and name when scanning an employee's ID. The issue above is preventing me from continuing to store scanned IDs after the first has been scanned. My current concern here is only with the ActiveWorkbook.save issue but I'll share the function's code just in case any of the other lines also have something to do with the issue.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ImageFolder As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FullImagePath As String
    Dim ColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim Errorflag As Boolean
    
    Errorflag = False
    
    If MorningButton.Value And AfternoonButton.Value And OvertimeButton.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Please select from the menu options before scanning"
    Errorflag = True
    ElseIf OutButton.Value = False And InButton.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Please select from the menu options before scanning"
    Errorflag = True
    End If
    
    'Column Index Value based on radio button selections
    If MorningButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = True Then
    ColumnIndex = 2
    ElseIf MorningButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = False Then
    ColumnIndex = 3
    ElseIf AfternoonButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = True Then
    ColumnIndex = 4
    ElseIf AfternoonButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = False Then
    ColumnIndex = 5
    ElseIf OvertimeButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = True Then
    ColumnIndex = 6
    ElseIf OvertimeButton.Value = True And InButton.Value = False Then
    ColumnIndex = 7
    Else
    MsgBox "Please select from the menu options before scanning"
    Errorflag = True
    End If

    If Errorflag = False Then
    
        Lastrow = Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With Sheets("Database")
            .Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
            .Cells(Lastrow, ColumnIndex).Value = Now()
        End With
        Label2.Caption = TextBox1.Text
        Label5.Caption = Now()
        
        ImageName = TextBox1.Text & ".jpg"
        ImageFolder = "\PICS CHRYSOS 1x1\"
        FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        FullImagePath = FilePath & ImageFolder & ImageName
        
        If Dir(FullImagePath) <> "" Then
            Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(FullImagePath)
            Image1.PictureSizeMode = 3
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not load image - File not Found. Please check file name and QR encoding if they match. QR Code is" & " '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        End If
        
        'ActiveWorkbook.Save
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
        Errorflag = False
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

EDIT2: Sharing Userform termination function

```
Private Sub Userform4_Terminate()
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it still do that if you change `ActiveWorkbook.Save` to `ThisWorkbook.Save`? (Just curious)

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `ActiveWorkbook.Save` followed by `Application.EnableEvents = True` to reset it. Also if the `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that you have the form in, change it to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Tried what Super Symmetry said. Still didn't work, I need to add another detail about the problem. After adding the save workbook code the form functions properly, preserving the ability to tab through objects - it is when I close excel and run excel again that the problem starts to manifest.

Comment: Additionally I have an Activeworkbook.save line in the Userform_terminate event function - Could this be what alters the properties so that it starts bugging next time I run the macro file? Ill try also changing this and ill give feedback

Comment: Still not working after applying what Super Symmetry said to the Activeworkbook.Save in the userformterminate function

Comment: Does the workbook actually get saved? Have you tried switching "Auto Save" on instead of doing it in code?

Comment: yes the workbook actually gets saved this is one of the things i verified by checking on the entries (including date/time logged) in the data table which match up. I'll check the status of autosave

Comment: You don't have an `Activeworkbook.save` line in the code you provided.  You need to provide the code/s that you use to save the workbook;  Per your statements you have two codes to save the workbook; `"and then after running a function that has Activeworkbook.save in it"`, and `"I have an Activeworkbook.save line in the Userform_terminate event function"`. Without your code, providing information on what is going wrong is just speculation and will not help you.

Comment: Please see that I added the code of the userform termination function. Thanks for pointing out that the OP lacked information. When I tried using enableevents and thisworkbooksave instead of just activeworkbooksave it didnt solve the problem. Perhaps a possible workaround would be to use the Returnkeypressed event rather than the submitbuttonclicked event.

Comment: I noticed another detail - during manifestation of the bug, pressing tab creates an indent in the textbox instead of cycling through the userform objects. Hopefully this detail might help explain the status of the userform during the bug. Also, i just found this stackoverflow topic looks like its the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714404/vba-tab-key-putting-actual-tab-value-in-text-box-instead-of-navigating-to-next-c

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the exact same macro file in MS Excel 2010. What I did on MS Excel to reproduce the bug no longer reproduced the bug. Problem solved. MS Excel 2007 is bugged. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set the `Cycle` property of your form to `2 - fmCycleCurrentForm`. Then, use `Application.SendKeys` to navigate to your desired object.

Below is an example code where I scan a QR code in the `Serial_number` textbox and set the focus back to the `Serial_number` textbox using the code provided:

```vb
Private Sub cmd_add_color_Click()
    Call addColor
    cmb_color.SetFocus
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"       ' Getting setfocus back to the serial textbox
End Sub
```